# call procedure syntax error?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Give the following stored procedure :

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS ric_forn$$
CREATE PROCEDURE  ric_forn (IN nome_forn VARCHAR(100) , OUT msg VARCHAR(100))
BEGIN
DECLARE num_rec INT;

IF (nome_forn = '') THEN 
    SET msg = "Attenzione il nome inserito non è valido !";
END IF;


SELECT COUNT(*) INTO num_rec FROM Fornitori WHERE Des_Fornitore = nome_forn;

IF num_rec = 0 THEN
    SET msg = "Nessun record trovato !";

ELSE

SELECT Id_Fornitore, Des_Fornitore, Ind_Fornitore FROM Fornitori WHERE Des_Fornitore = nome_forn;
    SET msg = "Records trovati:";

END IF;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

How do I run it?

I tried :

```
call ric_forn (Des_Fornitore,msg);

call ric_forn (nome_forn ,msg);

call ric_forn ('' ,msg);

call ric_forn ('EAN srl' ,msg);
```

'EAN srl'is a value

But I always get errors like Unknown column nome_forn or nknown column Des_Fornitore..etc

Comment: have you tried putting quotes around the vars? like `call ric_forn ('test',msg);`

Comment: I tried that but to no avail..I typed call ric_forn ('Nuova Elettrica,msg); but I got ERROR 1414

Comment: If I do call ric_forn ('Nuova Elettrica,@msg);it works perfectly but I don't get any messages...

Answer (score 1):

Try to run SP in this way -

```
SET @nome_forn = 'nome_forn'; --set your value
SET @msg = 'msg'; --set your value
CALL ric_forn(@nome_forn, @msg);

SELECT @msg; -- output
```

Comment: It works...I put what you suggested after : END IF;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
Is that correct ? Thank you..Is this the only way to call sp with parameters?

Comment: You can run it from anywhere as a script. String parameters can be set as string literals, e.g. - CALL ric_forn('your_value', @msg). The variable @msg is used to output result of OUT parameter.